# Get duplicate columns with a SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a User table with id_user, firstname and name columns.
I want to list all the duplicate values.

I did this :

```
$query = $this->db->select('user.nom, COUNT(*) as count', false)
                        ->from('user')
                        ->group_by('user.nom')
                        ->having('COUNT(*) >', 1);

    return $query->get()->result();
```

This works, but only for the name. It gives the name duplicated, with the count of how many times it appears. The thing is sometimes there are two users with same name but different firstnames. How can I check duplicates by concatening two columns ?

I tried to use GROUP_CONCAT with no success. I also tried to do this, I wanted to concat the name and the firstname, and group_by it, but doesn't work :

```
$query = $this->db->select('CONCAT(user.nom, ' ', user.prenom) as usr, COUNT(*) as count', false)
                        ->from('user')
                        ->group_by('usr')
                        ->having('COUNT(*) >', 1);

    return $query->get()->result();
```

What can I use to make it work ?

Comment: What did you edit the column name of user.name?

Comment: @gofr1 I tried, but the query doesn't work anymore

Comment: @f_anto I edited it because I wrote it in english before, and my columns are in french, I didn't want to get you confused thinking I was selecting wrong columns in the two examples

Comment: oke I see, have you tried as like my comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double GROUP-BY approach:

```
$query = $this->db->select('user.name, user.prenom, COUNT(*) as count', false)
                        ->from('user')
                        ->group_by('user.name, user.prenom')
                        ->having('COUNT(*) >', 1);

    return $query->get()->result();
```

CONCAT approach:

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(user.name, ', ', user.prenom) AS name, COUNT(*) FROM user GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1";
```

JOIN approach:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user AS a JOIN user AS b ON a.name = b.name AND a.prenom = b.prenom AND a.id != b.id"
```

Comment: glad to help you. But give the last one also a try, please. I like this solution the most :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add fullname in select command.
for this code:

```
$query = $this->db->select('user.name, COUNT(*) as count', false)
                         ->from('user')
                         ->group_by('user.name')
                         ->having('COUNT(*) >', 1);
```

please change (add user.fullname) to:

```
$query = $this->db->select('user.name,user.fullname, COUNT(*) as count', false)
                        ->from('user')
                        ->group_by('user.name')
                        ->having('COUNT(*) >', 1);
```

Hopefully it will fix your problem ;)